# Github API: Is there a way to get all the users with all the info associated with each user?

Tags: api, github, github-api

In order to get all the users that exist on Github, Github API provides the following URL:

```
https://api.github.com/users
```

But the problem with the call is that it doesn't return the full meta information regarding a user as clear in the following picture:

[image: Users will not full info]

In order to get full meta information, Github API provides the following URL:

```
https://api.github.com/users/<username>
```

The said URL does provide the full meta info of a user, but unlike the first mentioned URL that sends back 100 records per hit, the later mentioned URL send only 1 record per hit, and it slows down the whole process.

So is there a way in Github API that could give me all the users with all the meta info for all the users in more than one quantity in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there a way in Github API that could give me all the users with all the meta info for all the users in more than one quantity in one go?

No because of the huge quantity of data that would represent.

The only source of big data is [www.githubarchive.org](https://www.githubarchive.org/), which you can [get through Google BigQuey](https://github.com/blog/2201-making-open-source-data-more-available), but that only involve [GitHub event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/), which don't have all the users metadata.